# Compound Predicate doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of objects with name and address.
Both properties are of type NSString.
But when i'm using the compound predicate with both results i don't get any result. If i'm using just one predicate it works very well.
Has anyone an idea whats going wrong here in my code? thnx

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchString:(NSString*) searchText
{

NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name like[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *resultsPredicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.place like[cd] %@", searchText];

    NSPredicate *compoundpred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[resultsPredicate, resultsPredicate2]];

self.searchResults = [self.companies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundpred];
}
```

Comment: Is it normal that you're looking for something where the `name` is the same as its `place`? Are you looking for `orPredicateWithSubpredicates:` instead?

Comment: no, its about a company. which has a name and a place for example Berlin

Comment: Try: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name like[cd] %@", searchText]; NSArray *results = [self.companies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; for (YourCompagnyClass *aCompany in results){if([aCompagny.place isEqualToString:@"searchText"]{NSLog(@"IT EXISTS);}}` to see if you really have results. Maybe you want `contains` instead of `like`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using a single predicate declaration

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name like[cd] %@ OR SELF.place like[cd] %@", searchText, searchText];
```

and filter the array with it directly

```
self.searchResults = [self.companies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: thank you i tried the single predicate declaration but it still doesn't work and i have no idea why!?

Comment: now it works, thank you reaper for the hint with the single predicate declaration. I had to use "OR" instead of AND to get it work.

Comment: @dan: So I'm right, if you still want to use subpredicates, you can use my first suggestion in the comment of your question.